# Why is lighting broken while using shade smooth?

Tags: mesh, light, lighting

I have a problem with my mesh (blend file at the bottom), I want to connect these two sides of the object so the mesh creates something like a loop.[image]
Mesh is fine and smooth if those sides are not connected, but every time I try to connect them with "merge by distance" the lighting on "shade smooth" will break and the mesh will end up looking weird. I have no idea why is that. [image] My mesh is not that bad (I personally think it's clean). [image] I was trying to make this mesh as simple and clean as I could.

Here is my blend file.
[image]

Comment: Resetting vectors and setting by face fixes it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normals of your faces are pointing in opposite directions, possibly due to a scale by -1 ?

[image]

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> > *Recalculate Normals* (outside) fixes that.